# Jquery find a div with innertext and hide

Tags: jquery, hide, innertext

I have a div as below that i need to hide the specific div based on the inner text clause.

1. Hide div when inner text is equal to a word XXX
2. Hide div when inner text contains a word XXX

> ```
> <div>first div <div>second div <div>third div <div style="position: absolute; padding: 2px; top: 0px; left: 1px; color: white;">XXX</div>/div>/div>/div>
> ```

Comment: see the updated answer with a fiddle demo below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div:contains("XXX")').hide().parents('div').show();
// hides the div which holds the word 'XXX' and shows the parent
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6D3EL/)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('div:contains("XXX")')hide()
```

You should use class or id selector for div.say:

```
<div id="txtDiv" style="position: absolute; padding: 2px; top: 0px; left: 1px; color: white;">XXX</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#txtDiv:contains("XXX")')hide()
```

Comment: The first example will hide every `<div />` on the page if there's at least one that contains "someText". Just use `$('div:contains("someText")').hide()`

Comment: this is hiding all divs I only need to hide the div which has XXX but show 1st 2nd and 3rd as is.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$.each($('div'), function() {
    if($(this).text() == "XXX" {
        $('div').hide();
    }
});
```

2) You can use [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('div:contains("XXX")')hide()
```